# Applescript and Fantastical

Tags: applescript

I trying to add a Fantastical event with AppleScript. Aparently the Fantastical Suite is quite simple as there is only one verb.

```
parse sentence v : parse sentence
    parse sentence text : sentence to parse
        [notes text] : Notes to add to the event or reminder
        [add immediately boolean] : If true the sentence is parsed and immediately added to the calendar.
```

I've managed to parse the sentence but I unable to set the `notes` and `add immediately` parameters. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Fantastical but does this work?

```
parse sentence "my sentence" notes "my notes" add immediately true
```

Comment: That does work (although the result is not what I expected in the app). Thanks